# Opendaylight feature installation error which is not providing the required output Even after JDK 11 installation and maven 3.6

Tags: windows-8.1, apache-karaf, opendaylight, ietf-netmod-yang

While doing `feature:install odl-restconf` using karaf ODL installation guide here at https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-magnesium/getting-started-guide/installing_opendaylight.html I am getting below error and couldn't able to figure it out, this has stopped me to do development to some extent.
Please check and guide me as there were no errors ever before which would be available on internet.

```
     Error executing command: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi
.identity; osgi.identity=odl-bgpcep-bgp; type=karaf.feature; version="[0.13.0,0.
13.0]"; filter:="(&(osgi.identity=odl-bgpcep-bgp)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=0
.13.0)(version<=0.13.0))" [caused by: Unable to resolve odl-bgpcep-bgp/0.13.0: m
issing requirement [odl-bgpcep-bgp/0.13.0] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=odl-bgpc
ep-bgp-linkstate; type=karaf.feature; version="[0.13.0,0.13.0]" [caused by: Unab
le to resolve odl-bgpcep-bgp-linkstate/0.13.0: missing requirement [odl-bgpcep-b
gp-linkstate/0.13.0] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=odl-bgpcep-bgp-extensions-api;
 type=karaf.feature; version="[0.13.0,0.13.0]" [caused by: Unable to resolve odl
-bgpcep-bgp-extensions-api/0.13.0: missing requirement [odl-bgpcep-bgp-extension
s-api/0.13.0] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=odl-bgpcep-bgp-openconfig; type=karaf
.feature; version="[0.13.0,0.13.0]" [caused by: Unable to resolve odl-bgpcep-bgp
-openconfig/0.13.0: missing requirement [odl-bgpcep-bgp-openconfig/0.13.0] osgi.
identity; osgi.identity=odl-bgpcep-bgp-rib-api; type=karaf.feature; version="[0.
13.0,0.13.0]" [caused by: Unable to resolve odl-bgpcep-bgp-rib-api/0.13.0: missi
ng requirement [odl-bgpcep-bgp-rib-api/0.13.0] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=odl-
bgpcep-bgp-parser-api; type=karaf.feature; version="[0.13.0,0.13.0]" [caused by:
 Unable to resolve odl-bgpcep-bgp-parser-api/0.13.0: missing requirement [odl-bg
pcep-bgp-parser-api/0.13.0] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=org.opendaylight.bgpcep
.bgp-parser-api; type=osgi.bundle; version="[0.13.0,0.13.0]"; resolution:=mandat
ory [caused by: Unable to resolve org.opendaylight.bgpcep.bgp-parser-api/0.13.0:
 missing requirement [org.opendaylight.bgpcep.bgp-parser-api/0.13.0] osgi.wiring
.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.yang.gen.v1.urn.ietf.
params.xml.ns.yang.ietf.inet.types.rev130715)(version>=3.0.0)(!(version>=4.0.0))
)" [caused by: Unable to resolve org.opendaylight.mdsal.binding.model.ietf.rfc69
91-ietf-inet-types/3.0.9: missing requirement [org.opendaylight.mdsal.binding.mo
del.ietf.rfc6991-ietf-inet-types/3.0.9] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wi
ring.package=org.opendaylight.yangtools.yang.binding)(version>=3.0.0)(!(version>
=4.0.0)))" [caused by: Unable to resolve org.opendaylight.mdsal.yang-binding/3.0
.9: missing requirement [org.opendaylight.mdsal.yang-binding/3.0.9] osgi.wiring.
package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.yangtools.concepts)(ve
rsion>=4.0.0)(!(version>=5.0.0)))" [caused by: Unable to resolve org.opendayligh
t.yangtools.concepts/4.0.6: missing requirement [org.opendaylight.yangtools.conc
epts/4.0.6] osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))"]]]]]]]]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

ODL Magnesium requires JDK11, it is not specified in the installation guide, but it is in the release notes: https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-magnesium/release-notes/index.html

Comment: Again after installing JDK 11 i get this above edited error in windows 8.1

Comment: are you sure? that specific error is calling out that you aren't with java 11. do a 'java -version' before your start the controller

Comment: Yes, it shows 11.0.7 and also installed apache maven to